# How to call reflection method

Tags: c#, reflection

Is there an easier way to call reflection method instead of create methodInfo and object array as per below?

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load("Test");
Type t= asm.GetType("test.myclass");
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("foo");
object[] args = { 10, 70 };
Console.WriteLine("output {0}", mi.Invoke(obj, args));
```

Comment: Can't you cast the object obj to the type you have and then call the method on that object?

Comment: You need more description as to what you're trying to do.  Are you doing this a few times in one place, a few hundred times in a few different places, or millions of times in several dozen places.  The solutions for each of those would be different...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use dynamic keyword:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.Load("Test");
Type t = asm.GetType("test.myclass");
dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
Console.WriteLine("output {0}", obj.Foo(10, 70));
```

Comment: This won't work, if the name of the method is not known at compile time. Though it's not clear from the question if that's the case.